# Commpress a specific file extension into many subfolder with "FOR" and "7zip"

Tags: for-loop, compression, 7zip

On a server i have a main folder that contain many subfolder and file with some extension.
I would like to compress only file with extension *.bak and each file zip created in right subfolder path.

```
Example:
- Folder
-- Subfolder1
--- File.zip
--- File.bak
-- Subfolder2
--- File2.zip
--- File2.bak
```

Now I use this script to compress:

```
cd /Folder/Subfolder1
set extension=.bak
for %%a in (*%extension%) do 7za.exe a "%%~na.zip" "%%a"
cd /Backup/Subfolder2
set extension=.bak
for %%a in (*%extension%) do 7za.exe a "%%~na.zip" "%%a"
```

This script is right, but Ihave to remember to create new lines everytime that I have a new subfolder.
I there a solution that check every subfolder for *.bak files and compress it in each subfolder?
Thankyou very much and sorry for bad english.

**Addendum:**
I tried this command:

```
set extension=.bak
for **/R** %%a in (*%extension%) do 7za.exe a "%%~na.zip" "%%a"
```

this search correctly every *.bak in every subfolder, create a single zip for every bak that find BUT it create the n. zip file all in main folder...